# nth link scroll to nth li in the same order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of links :

```
<div id="links">
<a>A</a>
<a>B</a>
<a>C</a>
…
</div>
```

And in the same page also I have a set of tabs:

```
<ul id="target">
<li>#1</li>
<li>#2</li>
<li>#3</li>
….
</ul>
```

how can I make the first < a>(A) scroll to the first < li>(#1) and the second < a>(B) scroll to the second < li>(#2) and the third < a>(C) scroll to the third < li>(#3) and so on …….

**Note:**
The number of links and its targets not fixed It's dynamic, so I can't add id's to every item.

Answer (score 0):

Add IDs to your list elements, and link them up.

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="#link_1">A</a>
    <a href="#link_2">B</a>
    <a href="#link_3">C</a>
```

```
<ul id="target">
    <li id="link_1">#1</li>
    <li id="link_2">#2</li>
    <li id="link_3">#3</li>
</ul>
```

Granted, this solution does not animate the scrolling, so you jump to the location in the document. Adding a jQuery plugin that adds scrolling animation should work without changing the code, though.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('#links a').on('click', function () {
    //get the index of clicked a
    var index = $(this).index();

    //scroll to the li of equal index
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($("#target li").eq(index)).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Here's a working example:

https://jsbin.com/ruwacejifi/edit?html,js,output